# How to use $_SESSION in right way?

Tags: php, mysql, session

At the moment I am writing a little media library in PHP and i want to set sessions, so the user stays logged in and get's echoed his name at the front page.

**[index.php]**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
    //ECHO $USERNAME
}else{
    echo '<p>To start, please <a href="?page=login">login</a> or <a href="?page=register">register.</a></p>';
}
?>
```

I want, if theres an session id set, that PHP echoes out the $username.

**[signup.php]**

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");
$uid = ($_POST['uid']);
$pw  = ($_POST['pw1']);
$pw2  = ($_POST['pw2']);

if ($pw == $pw2) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (uid, pw) VALUES ('$uid', '$pw')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    echo "Registration succeeded.";

}else{
    echo "Please check your information.";
}

header ("Refresh: 3; ../index.php");
```

So, after PHP successfully compares my $pw1 and $pw2 i want to start a session, then it should put the $username in the $_SESSION array.

Of course next to the **secure** session id.

I repeat, after this i want to echo the $username out at front page.

What is the best way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: *"In the WWW i really can not find an useful explanation"* - I sincerely doubt that.

Comment: Is your question "How do I add username to the session array?"?

Comment: and why would you create a session on sign up page? what u must do, register user log the user in then store the session when the user logs in

Comment: 1. You're inserting passwords in plaintext - a absolut no-go. 
2. You insert them directly without any security for injections...
COntinue this way and your application could be took down in a few seconds... 
Why you don't use an existing system? :s

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/

Comment: Googled, "how to start PHP sessions" and got 46 million results, first one was [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).  The first example in there shows how to add data in the session as well.

Comment: Just for practise. If you have'nt noticed, i am new to PHP and first of all i want to learn the general PHP and SQL language. If this site will ever go online, you dont have to worry about my security Twinfriends .

@Masivuye Cokile could you please explain your method?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=$uid"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
```

You can do something like this.

Comment: This is about the only sensible answer given (so far).

Answer (score 0):

**Usage of $_SESSION super global array (compact version)**

```
session_start(); //To init
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Bob'; // Store value
echo $_SESSION['username']; // Treat like normal array
```

**Detailed example**

To use a session, you have to init it first.

```
session_start();
```

After that you access the session vars via the super global

```
$_SESSION
```

A good way is always to store a value in your variables you want to use:

```
// init session    
session_start();
// check if session var is set, if not init the field with value in the super global array
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])) $_SESSION['auth'] = false;

if(!$_SESSION['auth']) {
  //do auth here like eg.
  header('Location: signup.php'); // if auth is okay -> $_SESSION['auth] = true + redirect to this (main) script
  die(); // This is really necessary because a header redirect can be ignored.

}

// if auth okay, do fancy stuff here
```

**For security read the following**

*Remember to escape your user input, always!*

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

The session_id is stored in cookies normally.
Or - the old way via URL parameter.
You do not have to secure the session_id.

Read also advices about XSS/CSRF.
Plus tokens are also good. 
May be this is what you mean with secure session_id.

Stackoverflow: [preventing csrf in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780687/preventing-csrf-in-php)

OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard

OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: The question is about sessions, not about data protection/injection; stick to the question.

Comment: I'm wondering you guys thinkin about what i've planned with this piece of script.

Comment: Hope it is helpful now.