# Protect your delete.php links sended by email

Tags: php, mysql, security, hyperlink, content-management-system

How to protect my delete.php files

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$delete = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = :id");
$delete->execute(['id' => $id]);
if($delete->rowCount() > 0){
   echo 'SUCCESS';
}else{
   echo 'ERROR';
}
```

Lets say am logged in my website panal and my session is on

```
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = My_ID;
```

And some hacker send a link in my email while i am logged in

```
 <img src="http://my.website.com/panel/articles/delete.php?id=353">
```

That link is going to delete my article OR WORST a complete main section of my website and that is VERY DANGEROUS. So how can i secure my delete links from that

Comment: Generate temporary hash string that identificate email and user id. Place it in database. After getting deletion request, check if string exists in database.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287903/how-to-properly-add-csrf-token-using-php

Comment: it seems you are calling delete.php from your ajax cal send one token from ajax with id. Validate the token and id then apply the delete operation

Comment: Security Warning: md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)) is not a secure way to generate random numbers.

Comment: You can always use RandomLib https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build two step confirm form 
When user going to articles/delete.php?id=353, you just calculate some hash 'qweadasdasdqw' and provide link just like this articles/delete.php?id=353&hash=qweadasdasdqw

And just build some form with question 'Do you really want to delete article?'
button 'yes' will provide user to url articles/delete.php?id=353&hash=qweadasdasdqw ,
button 'no' wil provide user to list of article.

so if hash is correct, you will be delete this article

Take a look on the code

```
$hash = isset($_GET['hash']) ? $_GET['hash'] : null;
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
if (isset($hash) && (md5($id) == $hash)) { // Check hash
    $delete = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id");
    $delete->execute(['id' => $id]);
    if($delete->rowCount() > 0){
       echo 'SUCCESS';
    }else{
       echo 'ERROR';
    }
} else {
    $hash = md5($id); // Generate hash todo use more security function
    echo 'Do you really want to delete this article? <a href="http://my.website.com/panel/articles/delete.php?id=' . $id . '&hash=' . $hash .'">yes</a>';
}
```

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/775addadf1.png number can easily Decrypt you need to use php password_hash API http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good example, why it is stated in the HTTP RFC, that GET method should be used only to request the data, while [for the data manipulation it's POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5) method should be used.

And to protect POST forms from this kind of fraud, a usual CSRF protection have to be used. In short, each form should be signed with a secret token, stored in the session as well. So a site will be able to verify, whether the form was issued by the engine.

An example can be found here, [preventing csrf in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780687/preventing-csrf-in-php)

Comment: Hacker can provide some javascript, which make a POST request, hidden in the link

Answer (score 0):

You could do few things ,

1. Use post method for data manipulations instead of get.
2. You can also make use of tokens, make sure you ,regenerate your tokens
3. Don't just check if user is logged in but also make sure the logged in user has permission to delete / update that record .